# Line Up All Images With Same Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview

I have multiple text and images views showing up in a ListView the images are in different shapes and I want them all to have the same height and it's working sort off but now there are these huges spaces appearing how to fix

[image]

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>
```

Comment: fix the width of your textivew

Answer (score 0):

Your problem its caused by the textview with, if you change the textview content the size change and move your imageviews . You should set a width with a fixed value like 100dp, or play with layout_weight assigning proportional weights, something like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>
```

Or this (with weights):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weight_sum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"    
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
```